# logic when looping through multiple dictionaries and searching/comparing for keywords

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

This question is more around the logic of looping through multiple dictionaries and maybe if I am approaching it the right way.

I have a source folder full of yaml files which I will call "grants". My task is to go through all of the grants that are inside the yaml files. 50 grants per file and over 50 files. Each grant has structured data(dictionary) and I will be checking certain key:values from this gran to see if they're in other yaml files(dictionaries). These files are in other folders called 'users', 'groups' and 'apps'.

Right now I just loop through the grant files and then loop through grants inside the files. Then for each data point in the grant that I need to search for inside 'users', 'groups' and 'apps' I just loop through those.

Is this the quickest way to do this?

Comment: It depends on what "and then loop" means. The loops should be nested, outermost through the files, for each file loop through the grants in it...

Comment: Intersecting the keys() from different dicts before looking at the values would probably be more efficient.

Comment: At Michael Butscher - the outermost loop is opening each files. Then I have a function that loops through the other target files that I need to search trhough.

@Swifty can you elaborate, I don't understand what you mean by intersecting the keys().

Comment: Please provide a few examples of the files, their contents, and your desired output.

Comment: @Swifty I done some reading on intersecting dictionaries. The keys in source and target dictionaries are different. It's the values that I am trying to match with. See below example.

source_dict['value']
target_dict['id']

Comment: Ok, then you can use set intersection on your dicts.values(); but please provide (cropped) examples to make the situation clear.

Comment: @Swifty

All dicts from the source will have this structure '{grantee:{value: STRING}}'. I will loop through all looking for the STRING in that value.

Target files which I will be looping through will have the following {value: STRING}. So I'm trying to match the above with this STRING.

Comment: You mean source and target files contain a lot of tiny dictionaries? Anyway, your nested for loops will make an algorithmic complexity of n*p (or worse; please include in your question some ACTUAL examples of the different files); to make that more efficient, a first pass to reformat the data in a more usable form would help. But, once again, hard to be more precise without examples.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255000/discussion-between-barry-keegan-and-swifty).